# .htaccess rewrite across domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have 3 pages:

```
http://www.domain.com/page-one
http://www.domain.com/page-two
http://www.domain.com/page-three
```

I would like to have a new domain (e.g http://domain2.com) and map these pages to the new domain using .htaccess and Apache rewrite rules.

so the following would be mapped:

```
http://domain2.com would show http://www.domain.com/page-one
http://domain2.com/info would show http://www.domain.com/page-two
http://domain2.com/contact would show http://www.domain.com/page-three
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't truly do a *rewrite* across domains, but you can do a redirect:

```
RewriteRule ^info$ http://domain.com/page-two [R=301]
```

(It might be possible to simulate a rewrite with some cURL trickery, if that's really what you're going for)

Comment: is it a good idea to use a 301 permanently on a domain? any downside to this approach?

Comment: Well, why do you need pages mirrored between two sites? For some cases it would be a bad idea, for others OK.

Answer (score 0):

If both sites live in the same directory you could do something like this.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /page-one
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^info$ /page-two
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^contact$ /page-three
```